# Assign pyspark column based upon other column values using groupby average

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe hat looks as such:

```
 identifier    numbers_to_sum
 dog           5 
 cat           4
 dog           3
 parrot        2
 cat           7
```

What I want is to assign a new column with the values based upon a groupby average of numbers_to_sum related to the specific identifier. The result would look like this

```
 identifier    numbers_to_avg    average
 dog           5                 4
 cat           4                 5.5
 dog           3                 4
 parrot        2                 2
 cat           7                 5.5
```

I tried to do this:

```
df.withColumn('average', df.groupBy('identifier').mean('numbers_to_avg').alias('avg').select('avg'))
```

But I get this error:

```
PySparkTypeError: [NOT_COLUMN] Argument `col` should be a Column, got DataFrame.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` is a reduction operation that usually changes the shape of a dataframe and returns a new dataframe therefore you cannot use it with the `withColumn` method which expects a column type. Here you need to use `Window` methods to partition the dataframe by `identifier` in order to broadcast the mean values back to the group/original shape.

```
W = Window.partitionBy('identifier')
df = df.withColumn('avg', F.avg('numbers_to_sum').over(W))
```

---

```
+----------+--------------+---+
|identifier|numbers_to_sum|avg|
+----------+--------------+---+
|       cat|             4|5.5|
|       cat|             7|5.5|
|       dog|             5|4.0|
|       dog|             3|4.0|
|    parrot|             2|2.0|
+----------+--------------+---+
```